# Application of Kolmogorov's Three Series Theorem

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, convergence-divergence

Let me firstly recall the theorem:

> (Kolmogorov's Three Series) Suppose $X_{k}$ are independent random variables. For non-random $c>0$, let $X_{n}^{(c)}=X_{n}\mathbb{1}_{|X_{n}|\leq c}$ be the corresponding truncated variables and consider the three series $$\sum_{n}\mathbb{P}(|X_{n}|>c),\ \sum_{n}\mathbb{E}X_{n}^{(c)},\ \sum_{n}Var(X_{n}^{(c)}).$$ Then, the random series $\sum_{n}X_{n}$ converges a.s. if and only if for some $c>0$ all three series above converges.

I am working on this question:

> Let $X_{k}$ be mutually independent random variables and set $S_{n}:=\sum_{k=1}^{n}X_{k}$. Suppose that for some $\alpha,\beta\in\mathbb{R}$, we have $$\mathbb{P}(X_{k}=k^{\alpha})=\mathbb{P}(X_{k}=-k^{\alpha})=\dfrac{1}{2}k^{-\beta}\ \text{and}\ \mathbb{P}(X_{k}=0)=1-k^{-\beta}\ (**).$$ Show that if $\beta>1$, then $S_{n}$ converges $a.s.$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$ via Kolmogorov's Three Series Theorem.

I understand that this question can be directly showed by using Borel Cantelli, but how could I should this question using Kolmogorov's Three Series?

The problem I am facing is the choice of $c$. My idea was to choose a $c>0$ such that thee three sums have just finitely many of terms.

However, if I choose $c=1$, the problem here is that I don't know whether $\alpha$ is positive or negative. Even though it is positive, we still need to compare $k^{\alpha}$ with $1$.

How should I perform the proof here?

Thank you!